# Unable to connect sql server using php

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have PHP8.1 and sql server 2019 installed and the application is working fine in other systems.
Currently trying to run the same application with same above specifications and I am facing a weird error continuously. Any help is most appreciated!

Code:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => 'database_name', "UID" => 'sa', "PWD" => 'password');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(DB_server, $connectionInfo);
if(!$conn) {
    echo "Could not connect";
    echo ""<pre>;
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Error when I run the application:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => IM006
                [SQLSTATE] => IM006
                [1] => 0
                [code] => 0
                [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Drivers's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
                [message] => [microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
            )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 5701
            [code] => 5701
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][Sql Server]Changed database context to 'database_name'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][Sql Server]Changed database context to 'database_name'.
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 5703
            [code] => 5703
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][Sql Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][Sql Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
        )
)
```

I tried to run the application with sql server 2022 and sql server 2019 and checked the creadentials for sa user. installed different ODBC drivers. checked php.ini file to see extensions are provided with .dll location.

Comment: I (foolishly) assumed that was your code as it was in a code block. What is the code you are using then/

Comment: I have added the connection code that I am trying. Thanks